# ORA-12504 warning in PHP

Tags: php, linux, oracle11g

I have below script for checking Oracle Database Connection with PHP in Linux:

```
<?php
        $conn = oci_connect('proekt', 'proekt1', 'localhost:1521');

        $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select 1+2 as sum from dual");
        oci_execute($stid);
        $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH);
        echo $row[SUM];
?>
```

But it gives me this warning:

```
Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA in /var/www/test.php on line 2
```

How can I fix it and what is the problem?

Comment: because "oci_connect()" failed.

Comment: The "oci_connect()" problem is probably Oracle configuration (and not a PHP coding issue).

Comment: please check this link this will help you : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/error-connecting-to-oracle-database-from-php-837602/

Answer (score 3):

Changing the third paramter in oci_connect() helped me:

```
$conn = oci_connect('proekt', 'proekt1', ' (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = proekt)
    )
  )');
```